# ajax post with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to submit with POST method an ID when an element is clicked? I think jQuery has a built in AJAX fanction...

```
<span id="submitThisID"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#submitThisId').click(function() {
  $.post("postTo.php", { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(response) {
    alert(response);
  });
});
```

This will post your id to postTo.php and can be retrieved using: `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Whatever the postTo.php file returns will be alerted to the screen (response).

**EDIT:** To submit to the same page and do some server-side actions (db query, etc) you would only need to put something similar to the following code at the top of your page:

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // Perform some db queries, etc here
    $response = 'Format a response here'; // Format a response

    // This will return your formatted response to the $.post() call in jQuery 
    return print_r($response);
  } 
?>
```

When that "response" (text, html, etc) is returned to jQuery, you can use simple jQuery to insert it into the page where necessary and change the look of the page.

Comment: Can I submit this to the same page? I use PHP, can I replace postTo.php with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? I need to get that ID and run a query.

Comment: @santa yes it is possible to post to the same page. You could replace postTo.php with `location.href` to achieve the same result.

Comment: I come to realization that I won't be able to achieve what I need. Even if I click and get the ID of the clicked element, I need to turn it into a PHP variable to run a query and then update the page by reloading. Just seem too convoluted. Here's an idea for the next great plug-in. Click an element and POST id as it was a value of a form submitted -- but without a form. This front- sever-side coding just does not click in my head today...

Comment: @santa see my edit above. When posting back to your page you can make the id a PHP variable server-side and use it for queries etc and return a response to jQuery to insert it into the page wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
#submitThisID.post(
    'http://example.com/',
    {
        'foo': 'bar',
    },
    function (data) {
        console.log( 'data: ' + data );
    }
);
```

Comment: Cool, wasn't aware of post function. But How do I pass the value of the ID? Is it $(this).val() ?

Comment: santa: Sorry, I did not understand what you meant by `value of the ID`. Is it the HTML within the element with the ID or something else?

Comment: @santa if you want to pass the id of the element use `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible: [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post).

However, your question doesn't make sense. Submitted values in HTTP posts take on name/value pairs. An example [POST body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) might look like this:

```
Name: Jonathan Doe
Age: 23
```

Would the element ID be name, or the value? What would the other one be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a read of this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

```
              $('#submitThisID').click(function({
                 var id = $(this).attr('id');
                 $.ajax({
                    url:'/index.php/ajax/',
                    type:'post',
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{
                        id:id;
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                       console.log('ajax success!');
                    }
                 });
             });
```

Comment: i'm aware that this doesn't make sense, but the click handler could be on a class or something