# Storing Form element ID in variable?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, forms

I have an **HTML** form that contains the following code:

```
<input id="image_22" name="images[]" type="file"  />
<input id="image_8" name="images[]" type="file"  />
```

I'd like to be able to **store the form input ID element in a variable (e.g. $imgnumber = 'image_22')**. Is this possible? See my comment in the code below:

**PHP:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
        $number_of_file_fields++;
        if ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field empty or not
            $number_of_uploaded_files++;
            $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i])) {

                $number_of_moved_files++;
                // *** COMMENT *** // 
                $imgnumber = CURRENT_FILE_INPUT_ID - this would store e.g. "image_22"
                }

            }

    }
```

Many thanks for any help with this :-)

Comment: Hi Prisoner. Thanks for this. Can you explain how I modify my code above to allow this?

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163197/how-to-get-element-id-into-php-variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the `name` and value of inputs are submitted to the server side. You could code the ID into the name instead of using an array of files.

```
<input id="image_22" name="image_22" type="file"  />
<input id="image_8" name="image_8" type="file"  />
```

Access on the PHP side:

```
foreach($_FILES as $imageName => $file)
{
    // $imageName contains image_22 or image_8
    // $file contains the full array for this particular file
}
```

**Edit:**

Your updated PHP code could be:

```
foreach($_FILES as $imageName => $file)
{
    $number_of_file_fields++;
    if ($file['name'] != '') { //check if file field empty or not
        $number_of_uploaded_files++;
        $uploaded_files[] = $file['name'];

        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $file['name'])) {

            $number_of_moved_files++;
            // *** COMMENT *** // 
            $imgnumber = $imageName; // image_22 or image_8
        }
    }
}
```

Failing that, you will have to send the ID as a separate variable, for example using a hidden input or the querystring.

Comment: Hi +MrCode. Can you explain how I update the rest of my code? For example, how do I change this: `$_FILES['images']['name'][$i];`?

Comment: Hi Mr.Code - me again :) This part of the code seems to fail `if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $file['name'])) {` in that my script bypasses it even though I have images to upload.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk does your `$upload_directory` have a trailing slash `/`? It needs it.

Comment: Do you want me to provide the results of `print_r($file);`?

Comment: Your file inputs in the HTML are still arrays, update them to as I showed with name="image_8"

Comment: Thank you MrCode for all your time and patience with this. I was being a bit of a dope at times :/ Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in pure HTML+PHP for the simple reason that browsers do not send IDs to the server when forms are submitted.

The most obvious solution is to add the relevant information somewhere else, such as the `name` attribute.

**Update:**

Rather than:

```
<input id="image_22" name="images[]" type="file"  />
<input id="image_8" name="images[]" type="file"  />
```

... do this:

```
<input name="images[22]" type="file"  />
<input name="images[8]" type="file"  />
```

**Update:**

If you `print_r()` your input, you'll see what it looks like:

```
Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [22] => Test.txt
                    [8] => Blah.exe
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [22] => text/plain
                    [8] => application/octet-stream
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [22] => D:\Server\PHP\tmp\php7D2D.tmp
                    [8] => D:\Server\PHP\tmp\php7D4E.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [22] => 0
                    [8] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [22] => 3695
                    [8] => 432
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Hi Alvaro! Brill. Can you show me (using the code above) how I can use the name attribute to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the Update. Do I have to change my PHP to now store the the number '22' in a variable?

Comment: Yes, you have to change your PHP.

Comment: Sorry to be a bit slow. Can you explain how I change my PHP? I think we've almost got an Answer :-)

Comment: print_r($_FILES); gave me this http://pastebin.com/ASrbgnCz
How do I now update my PHP to include the $imgnumber part?

Comment: I'll be glad to answer any precise question you have, but I won't write the complete code for you. I have the impression that you don't really understand your current code, and that's not good.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, Alvaro. I appreciate your time.